# Displaying number of alphabetical letters and the number of decimal digits in C

Tags: c

I have been working on this simple code for hours now, and I have no idea what is wrong! I need to display number of alphabetical letters and the number of decimal digits in standard input. So far I have this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int isalpha(int);
int isdigit (int);
int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    printf("The number of letters is %d and the number of digits is %d.\n", isalpha(c), isdigit(c));
    return 0;
}

int isalpha(int one)
{
    int ch;
    int i;
    i=0;
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if(isalpha(ch))
        i++;
    return i;
}

int isdigit(int two)
{
    int a;
    int k;
    k=0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if(isdigit(a))
        k++;
    return k;
}
```

Program crashes whenever I try to run it and I have no clue what part of the code is wrong. Although I don't have much experience in this field yet, so any help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: The main cause is `scanf("%d", &ch);`. It can not be used in this way to read the letter.  It causes a stack overflow occurs call of function of one after another in order to read character is not consumed.

Comment: Also, It should not be re-define a function with the same name as the standard function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the existing API's gently and get the count as shown below

```
    int alp = 0;
    int dig = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
       if (isalpha(c)
           alp++;
       else if (isdigit(c))
           dig++;
    }

    printf("The number of letters is %d and the number of digits is %d.\n", alp,dig);
```

PS: Take care to flush the newline char if you have `\n` in the input

Comment: thank you! I kinda realized that I can't really rewrite isalpha and isdigit functions... I think I was supposed to only mention them, like in your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The example by recursive call

```
//gcc -O2 count_alpha_num.c -o count_alpha_num
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void count_alpha_num(FILE *fp, int *alpha, int *num){
    int ch;
    if(EOF==(ch=fgetc(fp)))
        return ;
    if(isalpha(ch))
        ++*alpha;
    else if(isdigit(ch))
        ++*num;
    count_alpha_num(fp, alpha, num);
}

int main(void){
    int a_c = 0, n_c = 0;
    count_alpha_num(stdin, &a_c, &n_c);
    printf("The number of letters is %d and the number of digits is %d.\n", a_c, n_c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Examples of Mutually recursive

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void count_num(int loaded, int ch, int *alpha, int *num);
void count_alpha(int loaded, int ch, int *alpha, int *num){
    if(ch==EOF)
        return ;
    if(isalpha(ch)){
        ++*alpha;
        count_alpha(0, getchar(), alpha, num);
    } else {
        if(loaded)//Already been inspected by 'count_num'
            count_num(0, getchar(), alpha, num);
        else
            count_num(1, ch, alpha, num);
    }
}
void count_num(int loaded, int ch, int *alpha, int *num){
    if(ch==EOF)
        return ;
    if(isdigit(ch)){
        ++*num;
        count_num(0, getchar(), alpha, num);
    } else {
        if(loaded)
            count_alpha(0, getchar(), alpha, num);
        else
            count_alpha(1, ch, alpha, num);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int a_c = 0, n_c = 0;
    count_alpha(0, getchar(), &a_c, &n_c);
    printf("The number of letters is %d and the number of digits is %d.\n", a_c, n_c);
    return 0;
}
```